# How to seed 10 million messages into Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka

As of my requirement on real time analytics I have to insert 10 million records into Kafka and on top of that I have to write custom consumer logic.But to fulfill this requirement how can I seed 10 million records into Kafka within 3-5 minutes time?

Preferably we want to use Spring boot as per the project requirements.
Please suggest

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any simulator/tool to generate messages for streaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40131580/is-there-any-simulator-tool-to-generate-messages-for-streaming)

Comment: https://www.confluent.io/blog/easy-ways-generate-test-data-kafka

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several options:

- [kafka-connect-datagen](https://www.confluent.io/connector/kafka-connect-datagen/), detailed in [this article](https://www.confluent.io/blog/easy-ways-generate-test-data-kafka).
- A command line producer like `kafkacat`:

  ```
  seq 1 10000000 | kafkacat -b localhost:9092 -t testtopic -P
  ```

  - For more realistic test data use this [in conjunction with Mockaroo](https://rmoff.net/2018/05/10/quick-n-easy-population-of-realistic-test-data-into-kafka/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try streamsets tool, it has a data generator functionality. It generates data rapidly. Also this will help you with connector and consumer/producer, in-fact you can do some processing & filtering also here so ideally almost no coding and you are done.

Comment: Nifi also has GenerateFlowFile

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple producer and `produce` in a for loop. I did it, it works like a charm.
Don't forget to NOT use the `.flush()` if you dont want to produce 1 msg/sec...